# Setting Key Frame Distance in ffmpeg as per Adobe Media Encoder

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding

I'm working with video on a website that requires the material to be seekable both forward and backward. It's similar to the effect that Apple employs on their page for [the new MacBook Pro](http://apple.com/macbookpro). If you observe the top most Laptop image, it has dynamic video that playback depending on your scroll position.

Now, I've been able to create a mp4 video that works both forward and backwards with little or no stutter by employing Key Frame Distance set to 1 in Adobe Media Encoder:

[image]

I've yet to replicate using CLI and ffmpeg. I tried running this command:

```
ffmpeg -i Vulkano-HD_1.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=96:min-keyint=96:scenecut=-1 -an out2.mp4
```

The source is 4s and I'm trying to force 96 key frames (4*24fps), but can't get it to work. The file created with Adobe Media Encoder comes out at 4.7MB, whereas the cli one is 1.6MB, so something is definitely up.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Full log

```
ffmpeg version 3.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Vulkano-HD_1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-12-19 13:33:58
  Duration: 00:00:04.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9382 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x816, 9358 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-12-19 13:33:58
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] 264 - core 148 r2668 fd2c324 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=96 keyint_min=49 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x816, q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-12-19 13:33:58
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   57 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=      27kB time=-00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed=Nframe=   80 fps= 78 q=28.0 size=     343kB time=00:00:00.91 bitrate=3062.6kbits/frame=   97 fps= 63 q=28.0 size=     638kB time=00:00:01.62 bitrate=3215.4kbits/frame=   97 fps= 35 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1598kB time=00:00:03.95 bitrate=3306.2kbits/s speed=1.43x    
video:1596kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.086879%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] frame I:2     Avg QP:21.50  size: 28347
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] frame P:86    Avg QP:22.75  size: 17547
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] frame B:9     Avg QP:22.97  size:  7561
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] consecutive B-frames: 81.4% 18.6%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] mb I  I16..4: 26.4% 69.2%  4.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] mb P  I16..4: 19.2% 26.8%  0.8%  P16..4: 29.9%  4.8%  1.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:17.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] mb B  I16..4:  2.8%  3.3%  0.0%  B16..8: 37.6%  3.9%  0.2%  direct: 1.9%  skip:50.2%  L0:43.2% L1:53.1% BI: 3.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] 8x8 transform intra:57.8% inter:94.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 24.4% 40.6% 2.3% inter: 13.1% 24.4% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] i16 v,h,dc,p: 32% 17% 15% 36%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 14% 27%  4%  4%  6%  3%  4%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36% 13% 16%  4% 10% 10%  5%  4%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] i8c dc,h,v,p: 56% 17% 23%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] ref P L0: 74.1% 10.4% 11.4%  4.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] ref B L0: 83.1% 16.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fc67d807000] kb/s:3233.87
```

Comment: See [here](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/16836/1871).

Comment: @Mulvya Awesome, thank you so much! Been pulling my hair.

Comment: @Mulvya Works reeeal bad in FX though, is this a known problem?

Comment: FX == AE? No. Works bad in what way?

Comment: @Mulvya Oh, sorry, I'm used to web dev terms. FX means Firefox. Safari and Chrome handles the video just great, but in Firefox it stutters  alot!

Comment: Noticed that Apple is serving mp4's for Firefox aswell, thought they used webm for Firefox, but that's not the case. Here's the mp4 file anyhow: http://images.apple.com/media/us/macbook-pro/2016/b4a9efaa_6fe5_4075_a9d0_8e4592d6146c/hero-screen/split_files/large_2x/large_2x_1.split.mp4

Comment: Use my command with keyint and min-keyint as `1`